# Async function not returning value, but promise

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have an async function: `async function getUrl() { let url = await ngrok.connect(3000) return url }`. By my understanding, an async function waits for the promise to be fulfilled, and return the value. Inside the function, url is a string, but when I call the function, it returns a promise.

Comment: I don't know where you think you learned that, but that is [not what async does at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await). Async just wraps a function in a promise, with the return statement triggering the promise `resolve` and errors triggering the promise `reject`. Await, in turn, lets you work with promises, letting you write `.then()` handling "as if it's a normal return", and turning `.catch()` back into normal throws.

Comment: Then how can I get the value of a promise without using .then?

Comment: There's a link that you should click in the comment you just replied to, to learn everything you want to know about working with `async` and `await`, with an initial landing page that quite conveniently covers the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
async function myPromiseFunction() {
  return Promise.resolve('hi')
}

(async () => {
  console.log(await myPromiseFunction());
})()
```

That how it works, you need to use await when you call your promise function or use .then/.catch(I recommend not to, and learn async / await)